# How to force a conda package to install and remove conflicting packages?

Tags: python, anaconda, package, dependencies, conda

Is it possible to prioritize a package so conda removes all conflicting packages to install a particular package?

Something akin to the following (which isn't a viable command)?

```
conda install -c conda-forge mamba --remove-conflicting-packages
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161933/ help?

Comment: Voting to reopen. This question is sufficiently clear for those familiar with Conda. Unfortunately, the close voters have zero questions or answers in the `conda` tag. In the meantime, the answer is no - instead create a new environment with only the packages you require for the project.

Comment: Thank you, if other people would find this useful I could do a GitHub issue feature request? This is in the same vein as my previous question.  I ended up doing a work around by doing the conda install revision 0, then uninstalling all of the stats/imaging/jupyter packages and this removed most of the packages.  After that I was able to add mamba and some other staples with very few dependencies. Though, it would have been really nice to just do `conda install -c conda-forge mamba --remove-conflicting-packages` if it was possible.